# Multiple v-for loops in same vue file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I'm trying to populate a table using three for loops from my api.

```
  const events = await app.$axios.get('/api/events/')
  const markets = await app.$axios.get('/api/markets/')
  const markets = await app.$axios.get('/api/runners/')
```

I need to make sure that the table rows index is runners since the runners column will have more runners than markets and markets will have more rows than events.

Like so.

```
Event Market
           Runner
           Runner
           Runner
      Market
           Runner
           Runner
```

When I try to do multiple for for loops in the same vue file I get this error.

`duplicate attribute key`

Why do I get this error from using id in separate loops?
My Question is how do I populate the table based on runner index for each row?

Here's my code so far.

```
  <template>
    <div class="course-list-row">
      <th style="width:5%"> Start date </th>
      <th style="width:5%"> Event name</th>
      <th scope="col">Market</th>
      <th scope="col">Runner</th>

      <tr v-for="(event, index) in events" :key=id
          v-for="(market, index) in markets" :key=id
          v-for="(runner, index) in runners" :key=id>
        <td>{{ event.start_time }} </td>
        <td>{{ event.event_name }} </td>
        <td>{{ market.name }} </td>
        <td>{{ runner.name }} </td>

        <td />
      </tr>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    export default {

      async asyncData({
        app
      }) {

        try {
          const events = await app.$axios.get('/api/events/')
          const markets = await app.$axios.get('/api/markets/')
          const runners = await app.$axios.get('/api/runners/')

          return {
            events: events.data.results,
            markets: markets.data.results,
            runners: runners.data.results,
            error: false
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('error', e)
          return {
            events: [],
            markets: [],
            runners: [],
            error: true
          }
        }
      },
    };

  </script>


  <style>
    th,
    td {
      font-family: ‘Lato’, sans-serif;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-weight: 400;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: left;
      width: 0%;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;

    }

  </style>
```

The api responses have key of id as below.

/api/events

```
{
  "count": 80,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [{
    "id": 103,
    "sport_id": "9",
    "event_name": "Guilherme Clezar vs Uladzimir Ignatik",
    "start_date": "12-11-19",
    "status": "open",
    "event_id": 1273804660340017
  }]
}
```

/api/markets

```
{
  "count": 128,
  "next": "http://localhost:8000/api/markets/?page=2",
  "previous": null,
  "results": [{
    "id": 151,
    "market_id": 1273804670840017,
    "market_name": "Moneyline",
    "status": "open",
    "volume": 1107.5453,
    "event": 103
  }]
}
```

Comment: No Runners is the largest then Market then Events.

Comment: 1. You can't have multiple `v-for` attributes on the same element, you'd need to use `<template>` elements for the two outer loops. 2. Where is the `id` from `:key=id` defined? It doesn't seem to exist in the code you've posted.

Comment: The problem is exactly as the error stands `duplicate attribute key`, You have 3 `v-for` in same element, This is the actuall problem, You cannot have more than 1 attribute with same name

Comment: @skirtle I'm new to javascript and frontend development. Is there any chance you could show me a quick solution to the problem so my loops populate the data? Thanks for your comments.

Comment: can you give an example of the content of `events`, `markets` and `runners`

Comment: @tomoc4 I can't provide an example without knowing what you're trying to do. To rephrase my earlier comment, you need to provide an explanation of what you're trying to achieve when you write `:key=id`. Specifically, what is `id`?

Comment: @Bravo I've added an example of event and markets. Runners response is the same structure with key of I.D

Comment: Does this actually boil down to a grouping/sorting problem? It looks like you are getting 3 lists that need to be grouped/sorted into a tree structure with 3 levels? Is that what you're actually trying to do? If so, what property is used within the runners data to identify the market? Is it called `market` and would it have a value of 151 for the example data given?

Answer (score 0):

Key is used to calculate differences in DOM when re rendering. Keys have to be unique in scope a parent DOM node (I guess).

Try prefixing your keys with something.

```
v-for="(event, index) in events" :key="`event_${id}`"
```

EDIT:
Actually the reason is probably that your id is not defined anywhere. Replace it with index.

Besides, are you sure you can use three loops on the same element? Never tried it, im always concatenating things in a computed prop... Interesting approach!

Comment: where that ${id} come from ??

Comment: Its called JavaScript template literal. Go read MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: I know that I mean it should be index instead of id

Comment: Yeah ive just noticed after your comment that id is not defined lol

Comment: @entio I've tried your keys prefxing but I get an error. I've set a bounty for this as I'm really struggling to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments its not possible to have multiple v-for statements on the same element, you would need something like this instead:

```
<div class="course-list-row">
        <th style="width:5%"> Start date </th>   
        <th style="width:5%"> Event name</th>
        <th scope="col">Market</th>
        <th scope="col">Runner</th>

        <tr v-for="(event, index) in events" :key=id>
            <td>{{ event.start_time }} </td>
            <td>{{ event.event_name }} </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr v-for="(market, index) in markets" :key=id>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ market.name }} </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr v-for="(runner, index) in runners" :key=id>  
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ runner.name }} </td>
        </tr>
 </div>
```

**OR**

To avoid using verbose templating as above, you could merge all three arrays into a single array, where each object has an id and a type and render as follows:

```
    <tr v-for="(entry, index) in combined" :key=id>
        <td>{{entry.type == 'event' ? event.start_time : ''}} </td>
        <td>{{ entry.type == 'event' ?  event.event_name : ''}} </td>
        <td>{{ entry.type = 'market' ? market.name : ''}}</td>
        <td>{{ entry.type == 'runner' ? runner.name : ''}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: I've tried both your solutions. The First one does render events and markets but Runners doesn't render.  The list of markets starts when the data of events ends. The second solution doesn't work for me. Would it be easier to change the data in the backend to be nested? I don't know why this is so hard to do with Vue.

Comment: Why do Runners not render? Are there console errosrs? And you don't need to change the data on the backend but it could be easier to create a new route on the backend e.g. get('/api/combined/') which combines the three data types .

Answer (score 0):

Though I think this has already been covered in the comments I'll quickly recap some of the problems with the original code.

An HTML element can't have the same attribute multiple times. While Vue templates are not technically HTML they do try to conform to roughly the same parsing rules, so duplicates are discarded. The original code has both `v-for` and `key` attributes duplicated on the `<tr>`.

Another problem is the `key` value. Writing `:key=id` will try to set the `key` to equal the value of a property called `id`. But where is this property defined? By default Vue will be looking for it on the Vue instance itself. I suspect what you meant was for it to use the `id` property of the `event`, `market` or `runner`. For that you would need to write `:key="event.id"`, etc..

The question does leave some ambiguity as to what precisely it is you're trying to achieve but the code below is my best guess for what you want:

```js
new Vue({
  template: `
    <table border>
      <thead>
        <th>Start date</th>   
        <th>Event name</th>
        <th>Market</th>
        <th>Runner</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <template v-for="event in events">
          <tr :key="'event' + event.id">
              <td>{{ event.start_date }}</td>
              <td>{{ event.event_name }}</td>          
          </tr>
          <template v-for="market in marketsFor[event.id]">
            <tr :key="'market' + market.id">
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td>{{ market.market_name }} </td>
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="runner in runnersFor[market.id]" :key="'runner' + runner.id">
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td>{{ runner.runner_name }}</td>
            </tr>
          </template>
        </template>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  `,
  
  el: '#app',
  
  data () {
    return {
      events: [
        {
          "id": 103,
          "event_name": "Guilherme Clezar vs Uladzimir Ignatik",
          "start_date": "12-11-19"
        }, {
          "id": 104,
          "event_name": "Event 2",
          "start_date": "13-11-19"
        }        
      ],
      markets: [
        {
          "id": 151,
          "market_name": "Moneyline",
          "event": 103
        }, {
          "id": 152,
          "market_name": "Market 2",
          "event": 103
        }, {
          "id": 153,
          "market_name": "Market 3",
          "event": 104
        }
        
      ],
      runners: [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "runner_name": "Runner 1",
          "market": 151
        }, {
          "id": 2,
          "runner_name": "Runner 2",
          "market": 151
        }, {
          "id": 3,
          "runner_name": "Runner 3",
          "market": 152
        }, {
          "id": 4,
          "runner_name": "Runner 4",
          "market": 153
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  
  computed: {
    marketsFor () {
      const markets = {}
      
      for (const market of this.markets) {
        const event = market.event
        markets[event] = markets[event] || []
        markets[event].push(market)
      }
      
      return markets
    },
    
    runnersFor () {
      const runners = {}
      
      for (const runner of this.runners) {
        const market = runner.market
        runners[market] = runners[market] || []
        runners[market].push(runner)
      }
      
      return runners
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

I've had to rename some properties, e.g. `start_time` to `start_date` and `market.name` to `market.market_name`. The properties in the template didn't seem to match the example data.

The core of my solution is a pair of computed properties that generate simple object maps that can be used to find the corresponding children at each level. There are various alternatives to this but it seems that the heart of any solution is finding a way to navigate the hierarchy from within the template. The template in my example could be simplified but at the expense of moving the complexity into the JavaScript portion of the component.